# Clarification on Unsung hero badge

Tags: support, badges

I thought I was eligible for the badge but it doesn't seem to arrive.
If I'm correct, I need:

- At least 10 unscored answers (at least 10 days old)
- At least 25% of the total of answers

Using the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/891042), I have my 10 answers:

```
-- How Unsung am I?
-- Zero and non-zero accepted count. Self-accepted answers do not count.

select
    count(a.Id) as [Accepted Answers],
    sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as [Scored Answers],  
    sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [Unscored Answers],
    sum(CASE WHEN a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end)*1000 / count(a.Id) / 10.0 as [Percentage Unscored]
from
    Posts q
    inner join
    Posts a
  on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId
   where
      a.CommunityOwnedDate is null
      and a.OwnerUserId = 2528658
      and q.OwnerUserId != 2528658
      and a.postTypeId = 2
```

But when I add `and a.CreationDate <= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())`, I get only 8 answers. However, When I use `and a.CreationDate <= DATEADD(day, -8, GETDATE())` I get the 10 answers back so I thought "Oh I just need to wait 2 days" but this is happening for a week now. Anything I'm missing?

How can I have 10 unscored answers that are 8 days old and not 10 days old for a week?

Comment: Patience is a virtue of the unsung hero, since their reward will come later.  Voting to Close as no longer repo as the badge has arrived.

Comment: I voted to close as well but I think the legit answer is the comment from @Stijn, I would accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data from SEDE is not live, it is only updated once a week. [The FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) tells you when it was last updated:

> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Sep 2 at 8:33.

Your badge was awarded in the meantime. Badges are not awarded instantly, a scheduled process periodically awards badges, so sometimes you have to wait for a while.